# We detected user data transmitted off device that you have not disclosed in your app’s Data safety form as user data collected

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-play, analytics

I am using Firebase analytics and user registration in my app. Do these both come under data collection according to Play Store? When I submitted the app, every time it’s rejected with the message in the picture below:

[image: Issue email]

If this issue is due to Firebase analytics, then what if I remove analytics from my app? Will the issue be resolved?

Comment: Yes they count as you are not keeping all data on device. Update the app content form on the Google Play console to include the data they have an issue with. Then the problem will be solved.